# Github action mirroring with automatic submodules resolve

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-submodules

For a project, I have two repositories. One in a github organization (with limited actions, that's why I'm mirroring) and one in my private account.
At the moment, thanks to github actions, I'm using `pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action`, to push code to the organization.

But I've come to an issue, I would like that submodules in my private repo would be automaticly resolved and pulled before sending to the organization repository.

Is there already an alternative for this, or should I setup by myself an action that produce the same behaviour ?